# Coding a photoshoped GUI for iOS devices

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface, photoshop

well... I have searched for a while on topics of coding given GUI elements by designer in photoshop format. But I have a really hard time getting it together. Just for an example. When I would like to make an app with only a simple LCD-Display with a timer, counting down, how would I start there..... Don't get me wrong, I am aware of doing the code behind the scenes to make the timer count etc.

But what about setting up a nice looking gui with glossy display effect? What is a "correct way" to implement such a gui? Taking a Photoshop file showing a glossy display and setting a UILabel on that? or coding the gloss effect programmatically?

This is just one example... hm... I do not find good ressources for getting a start on such a topic. I would be really gladful if you could give me a helping hand for a start.

Comment: erm.. what exactly do you mean by that? Have I forgotten anything when filling out the question in the form?

Comment: When you ask a question on SO, users will try to help you by posting answers, if one of the answer solves your problem you have to accept it as a solution. You accept an answer as a solution simply by checking it next to the vote number. Go to one of your questions an try to accept the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8030433/277021

Comment: Thank you Cyprian for the kind advice... just did that... Wow... i haven't thought about that!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the typical app development cycle, you would have the graphics people delivering graphics to the programming people, in the form of PNG files.

However, it is very well possible to render all kinds of things on the fly on the device. The blue shade on the tab bar icons in any app using `UITabBarController` is a clear example: the programmer puts in a PNG with just the alpha channel, and the system renders the blue shading.

Using Quartz Core (look for `CGContext` in the documentation) you can draw lines and text, and apply all kinds of transformations, gradients, clipping paths, etc. Using this you can create your own styled subclasses of `UIView` and such.

The PNG approach is generally the easier way.

Comment: Wow... that is an interesting bit of info.... so I would make for example a customized UIView with a blue background for my display, and the designer would hand me over a PNG with the alpha channel (maybe a white color gradient layer) to simulate the gloss effect, and I put that into an UIImage and place this one over my UIView. Is that right?

Are there any performance drawbacks when using mainly PNGs? So the designer could make them up in Photoshop and I use them in UIImage Containers to use them for a custom GUI?

Comment: It's not like that. The blue gloss effect is something specific to `UITabBarController`. Normally, the designer just gives you PNGs exactly as they need to appear on screen, including all desired effects. (the main exception being the tab bar icons) Performance wise, PNGs are generally faster than on-the-fly rendering. Custom rendering would give you more freedom to tune colors/gradients without having to get back to your designer.

Comment: oh, the second exception is the gloss effect and the rounded corners of the app icon. Apple adds it for you, so you need to supply a "flat" icon only.

Comment: May I ask a question regarding to that? Hope I don't bother you... so I would receive the Gloss effect LCD Display by the designer exactly like it should be displayed on the screen. But Ho do I ensure, that my Textlabel that I am updating with my Modeldata is "Behind" the glass?? Do I need then two graphic files? One with the GUI Background, then my label on that and on top of that the last one with the glossy glass?

Comment: Yes, you would need two PNGs.